# Prove or disprove that if $I+3A-A^2 = 0$ then $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following statement:

> Prove or disprove that if $I_n+3A-A^2 = 0$ then $A$ is invertible and
> the inverse is $A-3I_n$

My attempt was:

Suppose $A$ is a matrix of $m \times k$ order. Since $I_n = A^2 -3A$, from matrix equality $A$ must have $n\times n$ order, so $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$.

On the other hand, $I_n = A^2 -3A \iff I_n = A(A-3I_n)$, so only i need to prove that $I=(A-3I_n)A$. But I could not do it.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Use $A(B+C)=AB+AC$

Comment: $(A-3I_n)A=A.A-3I_n.A=A^2-3A=I_n$

Comment: What makes you think you *haven't* proved $A(A - 3I) = (A - 3I)A = I$?  Remember, powers of $A$ commute! 

Comment: Note that, for $A^2$ to make sense, $A$ should be a square matrix

Comment: @J.W.Tanner oh, of course.

Comment: @RobertLewis well, $(A-3I)$ isn't a power of $A$, soo..?

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 Well, is good, but i think we can prove from $A(A-3I_n)$ to reach $(A-3I_n)A$ adding up some $(1-1)$ to factorize..?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian:  not it is not but $A$ commutes with itself and with $I$. So $A(A - 3I) = A^2 - 3A = (A - 3I)A$

Comment: @RobertLewis so $A$ conmutes with any linear combination of $A$ and $I$ ? i mean with $cA + bI, c,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @EduardoSebastian:  You got it, bro!

Comment: Well it's a standard result that if $A, B$ are square matrices order $n$ and $AB=I$ then $BA=I$. The proof is [non-trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/72031).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this fact also, take $B=A-3I$.

Now , as , $AB=I$ , we want to prove $BA=I$

Clearly, $A,B$ are of full rank here , otherwise $(AB)$ can't be of full rank.

So, $AB=I \implies (A^{-1}A)B=A^{-1} \implies B=A^{-1} $

Now, $B=BI \implies B=B(AB) \implies B=(BA)B \implies (I-BA)B = 0 $

Now, as $B$ is of full rank, $(I-BA)BB^{-1}=0_{n×n}B^{-1} \implies (I-BA)=0_{n×n} \implies BA=I \implies (A-3I)A=I $